# C# Excel Interop: Найти первую пустую строку

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Всем привет. Возник вопрос поиска первой пустой строки для того, чтобы её индекс переместить в параметры диапазона диаграммы. Так как диаграмма строится статически( уж так вышло) - возникла проблема пустого пространства на ней:
[image: Пример]
Часть кода, где задаются параметры:

```
series.XValues = WorkSheet_4.get_Range("B2", "B150"); 
 series.Values = WorkSheet_4.get_Range("С2","C150");
```

Как возможно отыскать первую пустую ячейку\строку, и её индекс передать в параметры диаграммы?
Что-то типа:

```
series.XValues = WorkSheet_4.get_Range("B2", x);
```

Надеюсь, что такой способ должен решить эту проблему.
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы так нарисовали, что у вас в столбце B и С одинаковое число ячеек, нужно ли рассматривать ситуацию, когда в столбце B десять строк, а в C - двадцать пять?

Comment: @AK Всегда В=С.